# Applescript Excell saves column in an array but row as a string

Tags: arrays, excel, applescript

I am trying to save all the values of a column in an array. The code seems to work, since when I log the array I get the different values.

When I do the same think in a row though, the array stores all values in a single string

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    open file "file.xlsx"
    set colValue to (value of range "A14:A100")
    repeat with myDate in colValue

    --this works    
    log myDate
    end repeat
    set rowValue to (value of range "C14:X14")
    repeat with myTime in rowValue

    --stores values in a single string
    log myTime
    end repeat
end tell
```

My question is, how can I store all the row fields in an array like I do with the column?

Comment: When you see the log values for `myTime`, are they separated by commas ?

Comment: @CJK Yes they look like this (*1,2,3,4 *) but log item 17 of myTime shows only value 17

Comment: When I run the myTime in another repeat loop it works. I assume it stores them in a double array?

Comment: Then it *is* storing them as a list (array), but I suspect it’s storing them as a list that contains a single item, where that item is, itself, a list, i.e. `{{1, 2, 3, …}}` instead of just `{1, 2, 3, …}`.  Immediately before the second `repeat` loop, insert line `return rowValue` and see what you get back.

Comment: You are correct I get {{1, 2, 3, …}}

Comment: So it would appear that _Excel_ might store table data in lists of lists that help differentiate rows and columns.  I bet the column values aren’t just a simple list either, but a list of many single-item lists, i.e. `{{1}, {2}, {3}, …}`

Comment: Excel is not storing values as list of list, but the applescript 'range' does it as mentioned in my answer 2 days ago about your previous question Spy. Inside the loop, you must get item 1 of the element.